# Attemping two-way serial port communication in Unity, Serial.Write() causes freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

I'm building an Arduino controller to be used with a Unity game that communicates over a serial port. Reading data sent from the Arduino works just fine, but when attempting to Write to the serial port Unity instantly freezes and needs to be shut down from the Task Manager. I need some help getting the `SerialPort.Write()` to work. Below, I've detailed how I'm sending data from the Arduino and successfully reading it in Unity, and how I attempt to write data back to the Arduino but it doesn't work. I've got the controller sending button states to Unity to control a character on screen like so

**C#, Unity**

```
private SerialPort arduinoStream = new SerialPort("COM3", 38400); 


   void Start(){
   //setup serial connection
        try{
            arduinoStream.ReadBufferSize = 8192;
            arduinoStream.WriteBufferSize = 128;
            arduinoStream.Parity = Parity.None;
            arduinoStream.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            arduinoStream.Open();

            //arduinoStream.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 20;
        } catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log("Could not open serial port: " + e.Message);
            useSerialController = false;
        }
     }

    private void SteerAndAccelerateWithArduino(){           
        //attemp to read serial data and handle it
        try{
            string serialData;
            //attempt to read serial data
            serialData = arduinoStream.ReadLine();
            Debug.Log ("serialData received from Arduino: " + serialData);
            HandleSerialInputData(serialData);


        } catch(Exception e){
            //if there's an error, disable serial controller to avoid blocking on serial.read()/write()
            Debug.Log ("serial read error: " + e.Message);
            useSerialController = false;

        }   
        //flush the serial stream
        arduinoStream.BaseStream.Flush();
 }
```

And the Arduino is successfully sending data with a simple

**C++, Arduino**

```
Serial.println(buildJSONString(keys,values));
delay(30);
```

But as soon as I attempt to write anything to the SerialPort at all in Unity, it crashes. I'm trying to simply write a string

**C#, Unity**

```
        string serialData = "{blueScore:" + blueScore + ",redScore:" + redScore + "}";
        //write to serial
        try{
            if(arduinoStream.IsOpen)
                arduinoStream.Write (serialData);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Debug.Log ("couldn't write to serial port. " + e.Message);  
        }
```

On the Arduino I'm attempting to read from the Serial one char at a time, but it never gets this far because Unity crashes

**C++, Arduino**

```
void receiveStatesOverSerial(){
  String readString;
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);  //delay to allow buffer to fill 
    if (Serial.available() >0) {
      char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
      readString += c; //makes the string readString
    }
  }

  if (readString.length() >0) {
      Serial.println(readString); //see what was received
  }
  readString = "";

}
```

**Has anybody successfully been able to read and write from the same SerialPort in Unity? Anyone see something wrong here? Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag for questions about Unity game engine.

Comment: Show us the content of the debugger's Call Stack window when it hangs.

Comment: I not have posibility to test now with serial data. But sometimes when i use this i use Stringbuilder for unsafe and pointers data management from C++. Try to replace your string read/write value for a stringbuilder.

Comment: @HansPassant the Unity3d editor window freezes immediately as soon as I run it, the debug output is never even displayed as it's frozen

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676264/81306, for writing to the port,simply write _port.WriteLine("YourMessageHere");

Comment: @KamranBigdely the answer you have linked is not the solution for the linked question and also he wants two-way communication.