# Unity program freeze after writing to arduino

Tags: arduino, unity-game-engine

i am very new to arduino and unity programming. However, as i was building this project of controlling multiple haptic vibrators through multiplexer within unity i encountered this issue of unity froze (time out after i set writeTimeOut) every time i call the write to Arduino function. sometimes, it works for the first 2 calls to writeToArduino but stopped working then. I am completely lost on what is causing this problem, would really appreciate the help

**Arduino**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SerialCommand.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Adafruit_DRV2605.h"
#define TCAADDR 0x70

Adafruit_DRV2605 drv[7];
bool hapticOn = true;
uint32_t wait = 1.;
SerialCommand sCmd;
int input[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0};
void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;
 // Serial.println("tcaselect");
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  byte error = Wire.endTransmission();
  //S//erial.println(error);

}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //while (!Serial);
  //Serial.println("DRV test");
 // Wire.begin();


  sCmd.addCommand("index", indexHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("thumb", thumbHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("middle", middleHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("pinky", pinkyHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("ring", ringHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("palm", palmHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("indexOff", indexOffHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("thumbOff", thumbOffHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("middleOff", middleOffHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("pinkyOff", pinkyOffHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("ringOff", ringOffHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("palmOff", palmOffHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("off", offHandler);
  sCmd.addCommand("ON", onHandler);



}
void indexHandler(const char *command) {
  hapticOn = true;
  //Serial.println("index activated");
  input[2] = 1;
}

void indexOffHandler(const char *command) {
    hapticOn = true;
  //Serial.println("index Deactivated");
  input[2] = 0;
}
void thumbHandler(const char *command) {
    hapticOn = true;
  //Serial.println("thumb activated");
  input[6] = 1;
}

void thumbOffHandler(const char *command) {
    hapticOn = true;
  //Serial.println("thumb Deactivated");
  input[6] = 0;
}
void palmHandler(const char *command) {
    hapticOn = true;
   //Serial.println("palm activated");
  input[0] = 1;
  input[5] = 1;
}

void palmOffHandler(const char *command) {
  input[0] = 0;
  input[5] = 0;
}

void middleHandler(const char *command) {
    hapticOn = true;
  input[3] = 1;
}

void middleOffHandler(const char *command) {
  input[3] = 0;
}
void pinkyHandler(const char *command) {
    hapticOn = true;
  input[1] = 1;
}

void pinkyOffHandler(const char *command) {
  input[1] = 0;
}
void ringHandler(const char *command) { 
  input[4] = 1;
}

void ringOffHandler(const char *command) { 
  input[4] = 0;
}
void offHandler(const char *command) {
    input[0] = 0;
    input[5] = 0;
}

void onHandler(const char *command) {
   input[0] = 0;
   input[5] = 0;
}

void loop() {
 //Serial.println("looping");
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    sCmd.readSerial();
      //Serial.read();
  }

    for (uint8_t j = 0; j <= 7; j++) { //For all the 8 ports
      if (input[j] == 1) {
        tcaselect(j);   // Selects only the ports which are available

        drv[j].setMode(DRV2605_MODE_INTTRIG); // default, internal trigger when sending GO command

        drv[j].selectLibrary(1);
        drv[j].setWaveform(0, 84);  // ramp up medium 1, see datasheet part 11.2
        drv[j].setWaveform(1, 1);  // strong click 100%, see datasheet part 11.2
        drv[j].setWaveform(2, 0);  // end of waveforms
        drv[j].go();
        //Serial.flush();
      }
    }

 }
```

**Unity Code**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System;

/** A class to facilitate the communication between Unity
 *  and the Arduino.
*/
public class ArduinoInterface : MonoBehaviour {

    public string port = "COM3";
    public int baudRate = 9600;

    private SerialPort stream;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        stream = new SerialPort (port, baudRate);
        stream.ReadTimeout = 50;
        stream.WriteTimeout = 1000;

        stream.Open ();
    }

    // Writes a string to the Arduino. 
    public void WriteToArduino(string msg) {

        //
        //stream.DiscardOutBuffer();
        print ("Writing to Arduino: " + msg);
        try {
            if (stream.IsOpen) {
                //stream.Dispose ();
                //if (!stream.BaseStream.CanRead) print("can't read");
                stream.WriteLine (msg);

                //print ("this is the code");
                stream.BaseStream.Flush ();
            } else {
                //stream.Open();
                print("serial is not open");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stream.Close ();
            stream.Open ();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code. Where is "WriteToArduino()" called? Are you calling in in the Update() method? This answer has explained how to read/write a serial port--> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676264/81306